# Multiple errors while sending message on Moodle

Tags: php, email, smtp, moodle

I'm stuck with this problem for some time now: Moodle (an LMS template) should automatically send e-mail students about every little change in their courses, like new messages on forums, new homework added, new file uploaded, etc. - but it never does.

We tried everything. We set and reset the Email configurations, reinstalled Moodle, updated it, changed PHP version, changed and rechanged the CRON execution time (30s, 1min, 5min - we tried all common settings) and nothing seems to make the smallest difference. With this new update, Moodle is now giving some hint of what the problem should be: we tested a new setting, tried to send an email to a couple of students and here's the error messages it printed:

Error Messages:

[image]

Note that this didn't show before. And at any rate, it's as good as nothing, since we don't have any clue what Moodle is expecting us to do.

Our SMTP settings on Moodle:

[settings screenshot 1](http://prntscr.com/fh3eir)

[settings screenshot 2](http://prntscr.com/fh3f1l)

We are using PHP version 5.6 for our moodle website and the Moodle's version is 3.3

Can you guys shed some light on this matter? We'd appreciate a little help, thanks a lot!

PS.: I am aware that there are other threads on this, but, since most of them are directed to people that actually own a server (which we don't - our site is hosted on a third party web hosting) and none of them solved our issue, I'm opening a new thread on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this page of the documentation?

https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Email_setup_gmail

It looks like you're selecting the wrong *Security* parameter.